# check if URL matches the pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying this on Wordpress, i succeeded to convert the URL of youtube to be embed, but what i'm trying to do is to check first if the url is embed then leave it and if it's not well then it should be converted to embed, the convert part is done, my problem is that i don't know how to compare, i tried this:

```
$video = $user_details->get('embed_code');
            $search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
            $replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';

            if(!preg_match($search,$video)){
            $url_video = preg_replace($search,$replace,$video);
            $url_final = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$url_video.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

<div class="youtube_cls">
    <?php echo $url_final; ?>
    </div>
```

so i'm trying to use `preg_match` but i don't think it works, any ideas how to compare if the `$video` is format like the `$search` if not convert it and if YES then leave it ?

Comment: Give `preg_match` a shot -- if it's a match, it returns true, otherwise false.

Comment: i did, the code is above but it's not working...

Comment: That's what I get for not paying attention. OK, can you give a sample of the $video url?

Comment: yes, it can be `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUdt_aBmkwo` and then it should convert, or `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XUdt_aBmkwo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` and it should not convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works great -- just that *if* your match doesn't match, `$url_final` isn't getting set.

Swap the comment on `$video` to see both echoing properly under `$url_final`.

```
$video = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUdt_aBmkwo";
//$video = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/XUdt_aBmkwo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$search = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
$replace = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
$url_final = $video; //set $url_final to $video so if !preg_match, it still returns

if(!preg_match($search,$video))
{
    $url_video = preg_replace($search,$replace,$video);
    $url_final = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$url_video.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

echo $url_final;
```